# Django Admin doesn't recognise blank=True in model

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

When I try to edit a user (using a custom UserChangeForm) in the Django admin panel, validation insists that fields I have set `blank=True` in the model are required.

I don't know where to begin solving this; I had the same issue with the `CustomUserCreationForm` but reverted to using the default which works as expected (asks for `username`, `password1` & `password2`, creates the user with blank `display_name`, `bio` and `profile_picture` fields).

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.display_name:
            self.display_name = self.username
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    display_name = forms.CharField(label="display_name")
    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    profile_picture = forms.ImageField(label="profile_picture")

    class Meta():
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("username", "email", "display_name", "bio", "profile_picture")
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = CustomUserChangeForm

    fieldsets = (
        (None, 
            {'fields': ('username', 'password', 'email', 'display_name', 'bio', 'profile_picture')}
        ),
    )
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ["username", "email",]

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Try `required=False` in your form. For example `display_name = forms.CharField(required=False, label="display_name")`

Comment: @IvanBeliakov I really thought it wouldn't be something that obvious... thank you!!

Comment: Glad to be of help. I will write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#required):

> By default, each Field class assumes the value is required, so if you
> pass an empty value – either None or the empty string ("") – then
> clean() will raise a ValidationError exception:

So you have to add `required=False` in your `forms.py`. For example:

```
display_name = forms.CharField(required=False, label="display_name")
```